# Почему не работает класс динамической очереди для объектов реализованный с помощью потоков ввода/вывода?

Tags: java, объекты, очередь, io

Подскажите. Создал класс динамической очереди, реализующейся с помощью системы ввода/вывода. Т.е. объекты любого типа (благодаря дженерикам) последовательно сохраняются в текстовом файле. Проблема возникает при извлечении этих самых объектов из очереди, т.к. извлекается всегда только первый объект а последующие просто игнорируются. Скажем при заполнении очереди объектами Integer содержащими значения от 1 до 10 - метод Getin извлекает всегда только "1".
Вопрос: что изменить в программе для последовательного извлечения всех объектов а не только первого?

```
package Qete;
import java.io.*;
class DynamicOcheredj<T> implements Ocheredj<T>, Serializable {
    private int put, get;     //счетчики заполнения и извлечения из очереди
    private Object temp;
    public DynamicOcheredj () {
        put = get = 0;
        temp = null;
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("Qete/Temp.txt")) {  //очистка содержимого файла
            fw.write("");
        } catch (Exception exe) {
        System.out.println ("Oshibka1: "+exe.toString());}
    }
    public void Putin (T ob) {    //метод заполнения очереди файлами
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream
        (new FileOutputStream ("Qete/Temp.txt", true))) {
            oos.writeObject(ob);
            put++;
        } catch (Exception exe) {
        System.out.println ("Oshibka2: "+txt.toString());}
    }
    public Object Getin () throws ExceptionGet {  //метод извлечения файлов из очереди
        if (get==put) throw new ExceptionGet();
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream
        (new FileInputStream ("Qete/Temp.dat"))) {
            temp = ois.readObject();
            if (temp==null) throw new ExceptionGet();
            get++;
            return temp;
        } catch (Exception exe) {
        System.out.println ("Oshibka3: "+exe.toString());}
        throw new ExceptionGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы разве файл не с начала каждый раз читаете?

Comment: "Qete/Temp.txt" - "Qete/Temp.dat"

Comment: замена txt на dat ничего не меняет, извлекается все также только первый объект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, комментарий выше был действительно к месту. При каждом вызове метода Getin() происходило извлечение только первого объекта, поэтому я начал искать пути решения этой проблемы. Не знаю насколько филигранное решение пришло в голову, но тем не менее это работает. В программе для каждого из объектов создается отдельный файл в папке "Qete/Tempa". В качестве аргумента методам FileOutputStream() и FileInputStream() указывается местонахождения текстового файла составленного из (адреса_файла(String)+номера_файла(int)+типа_файла(String)).

```
    package Qete;
import java.io.*;
class DynamicOcheredj2<T> implements Ocheredj<T>, Serializable {
    private int put, get;  //счетчик заполения и извлечение элементов из очереди
    private Object temp;
    private int val1, val2;  //номера документов в которые сохраняются/извлечкаются обьекты
    private String txt, qete;
    
    public DynamicOcheredj2 () {
        put = get = val1 = val2 = 0;
        txt = ".txt";
        qete = "Qete/Tempa/";
    }
    public void Putin (T ob) {  //метод заполнения очереди
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream
        (new FileOutputStream (qete+(val1++)+txt))) {
            oos.writeObject(ob);
        } catch (Exception exe) {
        System.out.println ("Oshibka1: "+exe.toString());}
        put++;
    }
    public Object Getin () throws ExceptionGet { //метод извлечения из очереди
        if (get==put) throw new ExceptionGet();
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream
        (new FileInputStream (qete+(val2++)+txt))) {
            temp = (Object)ois.readObject();
        } catch (Exception exe) {
        System.out.println ("Oshibka2: "+exe.toString());}
        get++;
        return temp;
    }
}
```